# Using sed, can I make changes only to the regex match portion of a line?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, centos7

Can I limit string substitution to just part of a line that matches a regex?

For example:

```
A this matches Z this does not
```

And, I want to replace `this` with `that` but only within the substring matched by:

```
A[^Z]*Z
```

That is, the only portion of the line that may be operated on is as is shown below in bold:

**A this matches Z** this does not

So, that I am looking for the result:

```
A that matches Z this does not
```

However, see the actual results for something that I've attempted operate on the entire line:

```
% sed '/A[^Z]*Z/ {
    s/this/that/g
    }' <<<"A this matches Z this does not"
A that matches Z that does not
%
```

The above example is for illustration purposes.

**Recap:** Is there any general solution using `sed` to make changes *only* to a regex match portion of a line? If the answer is "no," then is there a solution that uses only software that is installed in a CentOS 7 minimal configuration (such as `awk`)? Also, I don't want to rely on third-party packages.

My environment:

- CentOS 7.3 [kernel-3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64]
- sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2 [sed-4.2.2-5.el7.x86_64]
- Bash 4.2.46(1) [bash-4.2.46-21.el7_3.x86_64]

Comment: do you have perl? `echo 'A this matches Z this does not' | perl -pe 's/A[^Z]*Z/$& =~ s|this|that|gr/ge'`

Comment: IF you want a generic solution that doesn't know the knowledge of the contents of the file, then you need to specify something like _start at first word, upto 4th word_ etc, since you provided a question with patterns `A`, `Z` answers tend to be using that way.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a generic solution. The substitution can be done on any line, but the only parts of the line that are candidates for substitution are those parts that match a given regex. So, the requirements include 2 parts: (1) the regex; and (2) the transformation that is to be applied for the portions of any line that matches the regex.

Comment: @SteveAmerige: All we need to know is what is that regex  when you say `that match a given regex`?

Comment: I can't say what the regex is in advance. I'm looking for a general solution. It can be any regex that matches a substring of characters within a line.

Comment: The trouble with providing a specific example is that people try to solve only the specific example. Perhaps I should have said I have a Bash function that takes 3 arguments: a regex, a sed substitution statement, and a file. How would one write a Bash function that performs substitutions only on the matching regex substrings within the file? For example, `replace 'A[^Z]*Z' 's/this/that/' myfile.txt` - would that have been a better approach to forming the question?

Comment: @Sundeep - Can you write up your perl solution and explain the perl modifiers? I think this is my best option. I know the `$&` is the matched portion, but I'm less sure what `gr/ge` means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `perl` is available:

```
$ echo 'A this matches Z this does not' | perl -pe 's/A[^Z]*Z/$&=~s|this|that|gr/ge'
A that matches Z this does not
```

- `g` modifier to replace all occurrences of matched text
- `e` evaluation modifier allows to use Perl code in replacement section of substitute
- `$&=~s|this|that|gr` expression to perform substitution only in matched text, `r` modifier gives back result without changing value of `$&`

Further reading:

- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression with capturing groups to match the part of the line you want, and replace only part of it.

```
sed 's/\(A[^Z]*\)this\([^Z]*Z\)/\1that\2/'
```

Comment: This is a specific solution that requires knowledge of the contents of the file. I need a general solution. But, thanks.

Comment: The only specific words this requires pre-knowledge of is `this` and `that`, and if your goal is to replace `this` with `that`, this is about as general as `sed` can digest. Did I miss something here?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin He doesn't want to replace `this` if it's not in between `A` and `Z`.

Comment: Hi @DavidC.Rankin - The this/that is just for illustration. I'm looking to perform some arbitrary sed transformation only on the portion of lines matching the given regex

Comment: Replace `this` with whatever the pattern is that you want to match in between `A` and `Z`.

Comment: Whatever it is, the capture groups will pick up the surrounding part and copy them into the replacement.

Comment: The regex `A[^Z]*Z` is for illustration purposes only. It can be any regex. In my use case, the regex is being passed into a function that is performing the substitutions. I do not know in advance what the regex is.

Comment: I think you may be gettting beyond the capabilities of `sed`, and you should use something like `perl`. Then you can extract the part of the line that matches the range expression into a variable, perform the substitution on it, and combine it back into the original line.

Comment: Perl also allows you to use a function to supply the replacement. So the function would receive the portion of the lines that matches `A[^Z]*Z` as its argument, it performs `s/this/that/` on this, and returns the new value.

Comment: @SteveAmerige Then put *that* regex in there! I don't see the problem here. You'll obviously need a little portion of shell code that interpolates $start $search and $end into the sed command. What else are you missing?

Comment: @Barmar - I just checked and CentOS 7 minimal includes python and gawk, but not awk nor perl. The perl solution might just be the best solution so far since I'm getting the impression that this is, as you say beyond the capabilities of `sed`. I'm going to have to decide whether I can change my requirement to also include CentOS 7 DVD.

Comment: `there is just gawk but no awk` LOL! :D Really!

Comment: @hek2mgl - Imagine that I have a function: `replace()` that takes arguments: $1 is a regex, $2 is the sed transform, and $3 is the file. The challenge is to apply the transform on the portions of lines matching the regex.

Comment: Your challenge atm is to learn the most basic steps of shell coding, or let's say coding.

Comment: @hek2mgl - last comment is not helpful

Comment: It is! I mean what stops your from using `sed -r "s/($start.*)($search)(.*$end)/\1$replace\3/"`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135563/discussion-between-steve-amerige-and-hek2mgl).

Comment: Sorry, I have not time atm because I need to go to work. Please try work with the command I gave you. If it doesn't work for you, I might be available later.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach:

```
echo "A this matches Z this does not" | sed -r 's/(A[^Z]*)\bthis\b([^Z]*Z)/\1that\2/g'
```

The output:

```
A that matches Z this does not
```

Comment: This requires that the regex be taken apart, right? That is, the solution requires specific knowledge of regex, I think.

Comment: @SteveAmerige, you have wrote *just part of a line that matches a regex* - how we can write regex without knowing regex ?

Comment: What's the reason for the capture group around `\bthis\b`?

Comment: @Barmar, no big reason, just marking sections. Fixed that. Anyway, it doesn't fit the OP's wishes, I suppose

Answer (score 0):

If all you can use is sed, it may be done in bash like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
str="This does not A this matches Z this also does not"

regex='^\(.*\)\(A[^Z]*Z\)\(.*\)$'

a=$(sed  -e 's/'"$regex"'/\1/' <<<"$str")
b=$(sed  -e 's/'"$regex"'/\2/' -e 's/this/that/g' <<<"$str")
c=$(sed  -e 's/'"$regex"'/\3/' <<<"$str")

echo "$a$b$c"
```

Or, you may use awk (faster):

```
#!/bin/bash

str="This does not A this matches Z this also does not"

awk -vreg='A[^Z]*Z' '{
split($0,a,reg,s);
printf("%s%s%s\n",a[1],gensub(/this/,"that","g", s[1]),a[2])
}' <<<"$str"
```

Comment: I like the ideas here. But, try the test case: `str="A this matches Z and A this also matches Z this does not"` that does only one replacement in the sed approach and produces only `A that matches Z and` in the awk approach.